# How can I add iteration information between iterations?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working with this code, feeding it in a chunk of obfuscated java script and having it spit out a bunch of iterations of it passing through and xor function. My problem is I need to know which XOR value, or which iteration of the loop, was the right one. How can I add some line breaks-ideally 4-inbetween iterations, and with the iteration value? I've tried adding a variable with a bunch of line breaks, and the current for loop value but it doesn't work.

```
    #!/usr/bin/python
    import os,sys
    import subprocess
    import re
    import glob
    from os import path

    perl = "perl -pe 's/[^\d ]//g; s/(\d+)\s+/chr($1^"
    userInput = input("")
    tail = ")/ge'"

    def deobBrute():
        for i in range(0, 102):
            yield "{0}{1}{2}{3}".format(userInput, perl, i, tail)

    brute = deobBrute()

    for _ in range(0, 102):
        print(subprocess.Popen(next(brute), shell=True))
```

Comment: Why not capture each process' stdout instead of them printing to the same stdout in a free-for-all manner? Or reimplementing the Perl code in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, i stored the output into a variable using check_output() and then I printed that variable after the string, and iteration number.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os,sys
import subprocess
import re
import glob
from subprocess import check_output
from os import path

perl = "perl -pe 's/(\d+)\s+/chr($1^"
userInput = input("")
tail = ")/ge'"

def deobBrute():
    for i in range(0, 102):
        yield "{0}{1}{2}{3}".format(userInput, perl, i, tail)

brute = deobBrute()

for _ in range(0, 102):
    out = check_output(next(brute), shell=True)
    print("This Is Iteration ", _, out)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python 3 has the *print function* which includes a named argument called `end='\n'` by default.

You can try changing your print statement to something like:

```
    print(subprocess.Popen(next(brute), shell=True), end='\n\n\n\n')
```

Comment: This was the first thing I tried, and sadly it didn't do anything.